# localhost recognizes .env file in my node.js sever but not on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

ok, so I hid a password in my node.js server using a .env file

```
const env = require('dotenv').config();
var pass = {
  password: process.env.PASS
};
```

It works perfectly and I can sign in to my admin portal on my localhost but I can't on the site hosted on ubuntu. I triple checked to make sure that the dotenv npm was downloaded on ubuntu and that my mongo database has the correct username and password in ubuntu. Is there another reason why its not working?

Comment: what's the output of `echo $PASS` ?

Comment: sorry, a little new at this. Do I just put echo $PASS in the terminal. If so nothing came up

Comment: I guess I'm wondering is the .env file visible to ubuntu. Its not like it shows up in the folder

Comment: Is it possible that you didn't commit your .env to git, and it simply doesn't exist on the server?

Comment: I'm not sure. my .env is in a .gitignore, so does that mean its not in ubuntu when I pull it? I cant actually see the .env in the terminal, locally or in ubuntu. But it does work locally.

Comment: I also did a sudo nano .env in my project and placed the password there but that didnt work either. Do I need to place it in /etc/environment? or .profile?

Comment: `.env` should be in `.gitignore`. you're doing it right. however, that means when you pull it , it won't be there to load. you will have to set the environment variable on your server or place a `.env` file there

Comment: I thought thats what I did by doing sudo nano .env in the project folder?